# Passing C string to a function that returns C string pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am trying to pass a C string `(char*)` to a function `lower(char *)` (as in the prototype) that returns a C string `char *lower()` to `main()`. But I am not getting the desired output. Point out my mistakes and suggest some techniques for getting the result.

(Note : `<string.h>` functions are not allowed & the task must be done with pointers). Here is my code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *lower(char *);

void main() {
    char pass[10], *pass1;

    printf("Enter a password\n");
    scanf("%s", pass);

    pass1 = lower(pass);

    printf("Lower case  ");

    int i = 0;
    while (*pass1 != '\0') {
        printf("%c", *(pass1 + i));
        i++;
    } 
}

char *lower(char *p) {
    while (*p != '\0') {
        if (*p >= 'A' && *p <= 'Z') {
            *p = *p + 32;
        }
        p++;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: At the end of the loop, `p` points to the end of the string, and you're returning that pointer.

Comment: `i` undeclared. `while(*pass1 != '\0'){` --> `for(int i = 0; *(pass1+i) != '\0'; ++i){`

Comment: You should be using a different variable to iterate through the string, so you can return the original pointer.

Comment: You should use `isupper()` and `tolower()` to test case and convert case, rather than hard-coding `32` as the difference.

Comment: Since the function modifies the string in place, why do you need to return a pointer?

Comment: Why are you printing the string with a loop instead of using `printf("%s", pass1)`?

Comment: Alternative to `*p = *p + 32;` --> `*p = *p - 'A' + 'a';` or `*p = tolower((unsigned char) *p);` depending on coding goals.

Comment: @Barmar when you were learning C didn'y you write such a functions? There is no other way.

Comment: @PeterJ By the time I learned C I'd already programmed in BASIC, Fortran, COBOL, PL/I, Lisp, Assembly for some years.

Comment: @Barmar OK so when you were learning the very first language. You probably did the same in that language.

Comment: although some compilers, like Visual Studio, will allow the return type from `main()` to be other than `int`, the C standard only allows `int` for a return type.  So this line: `void main() {` should be: `int main( void ) {`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the '%s" input/format specifier,, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer so the user cannot overflow the buffer. Such overflow is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: the `lower()` function is modifying the passed in pointer.  so when the function returns, the pointer points at the terminating NUL byte rather than at the beginning of the string  Suggest declaring a local `char*` in the function, similar to `char *modified = p;`  change nothing else in the function except replace `return pl` with `return modifiedl`

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `main` should have the prototype `int main(void)` a for good style have a `return 0;` statement at the end of the body.
- `scanf()` should protect the destination array from overflow by specifying the maximum number of characters to read into it: `scanf("%9s", pass);` and you should check its return value for successful conversion.
- you should use `pass1[i]` instead of `*(pass1 + i)`. Both expressions are equivalent but the first is more readable. Incidentally, another equivalent but surprising alternative is `i[pass1]`, don't use it unless you want to confuse the reader, which might be advisable in a password handling routine.
- printing individual characters with `printf("%c", pass1[i])` does not seem mandated by the rules posted: use a single `printf` statement.
- Furthermore, the loop test is constant: `while (*pass1 != '\0')` as you only increment `i` in the loop. Hence an infinite loop and undefined behavior when you access elements of `pass` beyond its end.
- as you pass the return value to `printf()`, function `lower()` should return the original pointer, not the pointer to the end of the argument string.
- you should not hard-code the difference between lowercase and uppercase characters, `32` only works for ASCII, not EBCDIC. `*p += 'a' - 'A';` would be both more portable and more readable. It works for both ASCII and EBCDIC, but might not for other less common character sets and the test `if (*p >= 'A' && *p <= 'Z')` is not precise enough for EBCDIC as the uppercase letters do not form a contiguous set.  Use the macros from `<ctype.h>` for a portable solution.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *lower(char *);

int main(void) {
    char pass[80];

    printf("Enter a password\n");
    if (scanf("%79s", pass) == 1) {
        printf("Lower case: %s\n", lower(pass));
    }
    return 0;
}

char *lower(char *s) {
    for (char *p = s; *p != '\0'; p++) {
        *p = tolower((unsigned char)*p);
    }
    return s;
}
```

If you cannot use `<ctype.h>`, use this less portable version:

```
char *lower(char *s) {
    for (char *p = s; *p != '\0'; p++) {
        if (*p >= 'A' && *p <= 'Z')
            *p += 'a' - 'A';
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
char *lower(char *p){
    char *ptr = p;
    while(*p != '\0'){
        if( *p>='A' && *p<='Z' ){
        *p = *p + 32;
        }
        p++;
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

why sometimes is good to return something like converted char pointer - to use it in other operations - for example as a parameter in another function call.

Comment: because OP wanted. Why strcpy returns dest? Silly question - because you can use it instantly as a parameter in another function call. - `parse(lower(s));` @KevinDTimm 12k reputation and you ask such a ridiculous questions?

Comment: The only change I would make to your answer would be to add a brief explanation why returning the modified `p` is a logic error. It's in the comments above but it would make the answer better.

Comment: It always helps to explain the problem in addition to posting corrected code. They might just copy-paste without learning anything.

Comment: Ok sorry. So it was just the coincidence. Actually it is strange question if asked by the experienced programmer.

Comment: Brainfart - mea culpa

Comment: hehe :) no worries